# Creating CSS divs that read top-bottom, left-right and overflow to the right

Tags: javascript, css, html, overflow

I'm trying to get my divs to flow top-to-bottom, but upon reaching the bottom of the window, overflow new divs to the right.  See template layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHRip.png

I've tried `css/javascript` combinations of... `white-space:nowrap`, `display: inline`, `display: table`, `float:left`, and others but can't seem to get it working like in the diagram.

Comment: @Jawad Cool, this is _almost_ exactly what I'm looking for, though it still overflows vertically downward rather than horizontally to the right.  I added `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;` but that didn't seem to fix it.  I'll keep investigating...

Comment: That depends on the width of the div#container. The div.box and div.class will flow horizontally as long as there is enough space on the right. Once you run out of space, they will flow vertically. Add max-height: 350px; and width: 100%; to the div#container. Add some more div.box and div.sub and you will see that they will flow horizontally. With float, this will always be the case i.e., if space if avaible, it will float right, but once you run out of space they will go down - http://jsfiddle.net/AKW5A/1/ - do you want me to make this an answer?

Comment: I see now.  You've confirmed my suspicion that there's no way to set the width automatically and have objects overflow to the right (similar to the default behavior of overflowing downward).  I'm currently keeping track of the `totalWidth` of all the boxes and setting the `div#container` width to `totalWidth` at the end, which seems to accomplish the layout I'm looking for.  And sure, make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

http://jsfiddle.net/nPSUM/

Second

http://jsfiddle.net/AKW5A/1/

Comment: @arcoraven: For you approval!

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: right` on each of the divs

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/wzYpV/
(make the pane larger and smaller to see the effect)

---

Here is a fiddle that makes columns: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/wzYpV/

I used jQuery:

```
var maxHeight = $('.overflow').height();
var floatHeight = $('.float').height();
var amountOfFloat = $('.float').length;

if(floatHeight * amountOfFloat > maxHeight){
    var minPer = Math.floor(maxHeight / floatHeight);
    var overflow = $('.overflow');
    $('.float').each(function(index, item){
        console.log(item, index);
        if(index%minPer == 0 && index != 0){
            overflow = $('<div>', {class: 'overflow'});
            $('body').append(overflow);
        }
        $(item).appendTo(overflow);
    })
}
```

Comment: OP wants semantic ordering+display. floating right would put the first div on the right side of the screen, which isn't semantic ordering.

Comment: I think he wants the `div`s to be in (pseudo) *columns*, not just `float: right;`

Comment: @David... hmmm ok. coming up with a js solution.

Comment: The `div`s don't _have_ to be in columns.  The important thing is the flow (top to bottom until I hit the end of the screen/window, then left to right).  Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not really fully supported yet but multi-column layouts are in CSS3.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: I'd be open to using multi-column layouts.  Would a combination of multi-column and forcing horizontal overlow (how do I do this?) do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

So how about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/nPSUM/6/

i think it doesnt quite act like youd want it to but its pretty close.. i think..