# How to make elements flow down then across in a responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scenario where I am using a responsive layout to have a horizontal scrolling "menu" with `overflow-x:scroll` when the screen size is small and to have it vertical with `overflow-y:scroll` once it will fit vertically.

The problem that I am having is that when its horizontal, the flow of the inners is currently left to right and when the box is full, the rest are hidden and they are not being pushed further along the x-axis.

I have tried several suggestions that I have found [here](https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586875/creating-css-divs-that-read-top-bottom-left-right-and-overflow-to-the-right). I also tried to use `transform:rotate(90deg);` on the outer and then `transform:rotate(-90deg);` on the inners but it seemed to [break the rest of the layout](http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/uhpevyt8/7/).

I have been looking at `flex` but as I need to support IE8+ it's not an option.

This snippet demonstrates the problem: (the JavaScript is not part of the problem, its only used to demonstrate the issue)

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('#responsive').toggleClass('vertical');
});

var blockString = "",
    blocks = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
            blockString += '<span style="background-color: #' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16) + '">' + i + '</span>'
        }
    }
blocks();

$('#responsive').append(blockString);
```

```css
#responsive {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #aaa;
}

#responsive.vertical {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#responsive > span {
    width:130px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
#panel {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #aaa;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

#responsive.vertical + #panel {
    margin-left:220px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">Toggle Layout</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="responsive" class="vertical">
</div>
<div id="panel">Here is the main page</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

$('#toggle').on('click', function() {

  if ($('#responsive').hasClass('vertical')) {
    $('#responsive').toggleClass('vertical');
    $('#container').toggleClass('vertical');
    $('#responsive').addClass('horizontal');
    $('#container').addClass('horizontal');
  } else {
    $('#responsive').toggleClass('vertical');
    $('#container').toggleClass('vertical');
    $('#responsive').removeClass('horizontal');
    $('#container').removeClass('horizontal');
  }
});

var blockString = "",
  blocks = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
      if (i != 40) {
        blockString += '<span style="background-color: #' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16) + '">' + i + '</span>';
      } else {
        blockString += '<span style="background-color: #' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16) + '">' + i + '</span><br/>';
      }
    }
  }
blocks();

$('#container').append(blockString);
```

```css
#responsive {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #aaa;
}
#responsive.vertical {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#responsive.horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#container {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  width: inherit;
}
#container.vertical {
  height: 400px;
  width: 95%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#container > span {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
#panel {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #aaa;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#responsive.vertical + #panel {
  margin-left: 220px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">Toggle Layout</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="responsive" class="vertical">
  <div id="container" class="vertical">

  </div>
</div>
<div id="panel">Here is the main page</div>
```

Comment: I added an extra div as a container to the span elements, to make any CSS adjustments easier without breaking the top container "responsive".

Comment: Thanks for this, the problem with your answer is that you have given a fixed width of 3800px to this `container` which works as you would expect in the demo. However, in the real world it will not be populated by 80 equal sized rectangles but between 1 and 1000 randomly sized objects.

Comment: I updated my answer to not extend the width for these 80 elements.
However, you have to somehow indicate when do you want the elements to break a line (I set it to 40 check JS part) so as to not have all the elements in one line.

Comment: Main difference here is `white-space: nowrap` usage and the use of an extra CSS class **horizontal** which is added/removed accordingly.